# How do we set Product name, Company name, etc. in Setup and Deployment Projects?

Tags: c#, .net, setup-deployment

In my Windows application I set the Title, Product Name and Company Name in the assembly.

I added a setup and deployment project to the solution and added the primary output of the Windows application to it.

When I launch the setup, it does not take the Title, Product Name and Company Name.

What am I doing wrong/forgetting?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer, click on your setup and deployment project and then click on the properties tab (or just press F4). The settings you are looking for are there.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Lol I right-clicked and clicked on Properties - I think that gives the file properties. I'll accept the answer in another 7 minutes as there's a time restriction.

Comment: Thanks to Greg as well for link to documentation

Comment: what about the icon of the setup ? @Rohland